# Sorting from a nested array MongoDB

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to work with my data. So far I've got this here

```
    const personal = await culvertSchema.aggregate([
      { $match: { "characters.name": selectedCharacter } },
      { $unwind: "$characters" },
      { $sort: { "characters.scores.score": -1 } },
      { $limit: 1 },
    ]);
```

but it does not seem to work in sorting the 'scores'. Or maybe I'm not even accessing them correctly. I'm not sure. How would I be able to sort the scores of the given character name?

Here's my structure:

```
{
  "_id": "336277029060345856",
  "characters": [
    {
      "name": "druu",
      "scores": [
        {
          "date": "09/03/23",
          "score": 41
        },
        {
          "date": "09/03/23",
          "score": 12
        },
        {
          "date": "09/03/23",
          "score": 52
        },
        {
          "date": "09/03/23",
          "score": 100
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "druuwu",
      "scores": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The result you want is sorting the element by `score` within the `scores` array? Can I know which MongoDB version used?

Comment: Have you checked out [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/), which available in MongoDB v5.2+?

Comment: im using the latest version of mongoDB. i haven't checked out $sortaArray, how would i implement it here? im not too sure what im doing even with the current $sort

Comment: and yeah @YongShun . sort the scores array by the value of score in each object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a `$sortArray` after your current `$unwind`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$characters"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "characters.name": "druu"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "characters.scores": {
        "$sortArray": {
          "input": "$characters.scores",
          "sortBy": {
            "score": -1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h6iFQhT2-mE)

Comment: thanks this seems to work! however i forgot to mention, how would i make this only display the character 'druu' and not both characters?

Comment: @Hypo updated the answer. Currently, you are matching character name at whole document level, which will match when **any** name in array is `druu`. To work around that, just move the `$match` after the `$unwind` so you are matching at array entry level.

Comment: thats actually crazy i didnt know you could do that. thanks a lot!